# How to fetch api data and view in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, api

In my code, I want to fetch data from api and view in html table using javascript.

```js
fetch("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees").then(
  res => {
    res.json().then(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.length > 0) {

          var temp = "";
          data.forEach((itemData) => {
            temp += "<tr>";
            temp += "<td>" + itemData.id + "</td>";
            temp += "<td>" + itemData.employee_name + "</td>";
            temp += "<td>" + itemData.employee_salary + "</td>";
          });
          document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = temp;
        }
      }
    )
  }
)
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Employee Name</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="data">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

The api data can view but when I want to view those data to html table is shows nothing. any idea how I show those fetched data into the html table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have been using the `data` object. But if you inspect the console your array is inside `data.data`. So you need to use `data.data` to iterate over the array.

```js
fetch("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees").then(
  res => {
    res.json().then(
      data => {
        console.log(data.data);
        if (data.data.length > 0) {

          var temp = "";
          data.data.forEach((itemData) => {
            temp += "<tr>";
            temp += "<td>" + itemData.id + "</td>";
            temp += "<td>" + itemData.employee_name + "</td>";
            temp += "<td>" + itemData.employee_salary + "</td></tr>";
          });
          document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = temp;
        }
      }
    )
  }
)
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Employee Name</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="data">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```