# how to put API data inside exist html table

Tags: jquery, axios

I created the table with html and css which can sort, search and etc...

[image: html table pic]

```
<section id="about" class="about">
  <div class="container">
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Office</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Start date</th>
              <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
              <td>System Architect</td>
              <td>Edinburgh</td>
              <td>61</td>
              <td>2011-04-25</td>
              <td>$320,800</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Garrett Winters</td>
              <td>Accountant</td>
              <td>Tokyo</td>
              <td>63</td>
              <td>2011-07-25</td>
              <td>$170,750</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
              <td>Fiona Green</td>
              <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
              <td>San Francisco</td>
              <td>48</td>
              <td>2010-03-11</td>
              <td>$850,000</td>
          </tr>

      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
          <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Office</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Start date</th>
              <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
      </tfoot>
  </table>



  </div>
</section><!-- End About Section -->
```

I'm dealing with put API data inside existing table, but most tutorial I found is creating a new one
[such as this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvjaRIM4Bjs&ab_channel=LearnWebCode).

or [others stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64458283/how-to-fetch-api-data-and-view-in-html-table) is also creating new table without  sort, search... function.

So how can I do, any suggestion or resource I can lookup?

Comment: Whats wrong with creating a brand new table - whats so special about the one you've created beforehand?

Comment: hi, @Nick.McDermaid cause I have no confidence create new table with  sort, search function. So to input api data into exist function table is easier or create new function table is easier?(i don't know the way though, if you know just let me know thanks)

Comment: You have no confidence create new table with sort, search function? But that is the objective here right? Just try something... anything, do some troubleshooting with F12 console. Trying to preserve your existing table is just holding you up. To have a table populated from an API you normally just have a placeholder `<div>` and whatever javascript library you choose builds the table on that. You don't go and create the table manually first. The static data you've created in it bears no corellation with whatever is in the API